# Add number into String.format

Tags: java, sql

I want to add number into this code:

String.format(" WHERE e.id = CONCAT('%',%d,'%') ORDER BY e.id ASC", idParam);

When I try to send param `4` for example I want to match also values like:

`144` or `400` What is the proper way to implement his for numbers?

Comment: probably the desired result should be `"WHERE e.id LIKE '%4%' ORDER BY e.id ASC"`? If so, `String.format("WHERE e.id LIKE '%%%d%%' ORDER BY e.id ASC", idParam);`

Answer (score 0):

You should double the % to escape it like this

```
String.format(" WHERE e.id = CONCAT('%%',%d,'%%') ORDER BY e.id ASC", idParam);
```

the output
  `WHERE e.id = CONCAT('%',4,'%') ORDER BY e.id ASC`